# Jquery/Javascript and Css condition doesn't work on firefox and IE. It works on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, if-statement

```
$('.myclassname').mouseover(function(){

  if($(this).children('span').css('font-weight')=='normal')

  {..do something... }

}
```

Why the "do something" works on Chrome but not on Firefox 16 and Internet Explorer 9?
If I delete the if condition it works, but I need it so I can't delete.
Here's the css

```
div.myclassname span {...; font-weight:normal ; ...}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the HTML markup you're working with?

Comment: And do you really have a blank line before the `{}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
if($(this).children('span').css('font-weight')=='400')
```

or

```
if($(this).children('span').css('font-weight')==400)
```

check here http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/qpEK2/2/ `font-weight` return 400 in JS.

Comment: IT WORKS! Tested on Firefox and IE.

Comment: Sorry. I have to be more precise. 400 works only with IE and FF. Doesn't work on Chrome. To make it works I added an OR and my original condition 'normal'. If you have another solution feel free to write it. Thanks

Comment: @CalCon I would do the same by adding `OR` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($(this).children('span').eq(0).css('font-weight')=='normal')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you set it up in jsfiddle? Does:

```
$('.myclassname').mouseover(function(){
    $('span',$(this)).each(function(){
      if($(this).css('font-weight')=='normal'){
       //do something
      }
    });
});
```

Work?